# Using cookies or something else to restore state of drop list box which controls PHP variables

Tags: php, cookies, drop-down-menu, youtube

Okay just to be clear, I have really limited knowledge of php. Now, i'm trying to make a script that generates random youtube videos based on number of views, country and category like this one [here](http://www.flyhour.tv/index.php) using their api. I managed to get a working drop list to select minimum number of views the video has to have to be shown - its working pretty nicely (next ill try to make the other two work), but the issue is that i dont know how to make the drop list keep the selected value after the page is refreshed. That feature is pretty important since i want to be able to select the minimum number of views and want it to stay at that number until i select adifferent one from the drop list. I really dont know what method to use, please help me. Also i set the initial value of `$views` to be `0 + $_REQUEST['views'].` because it is later a part of a link so it needs to be a number. Do you thing if there is a better method of fixing that issue?
[this is a link](http://random.matepece.com/random.php) to the test site if you want to see and th code is below:

```
<body>
<?php 
$views = 0 + $_REQUEST['views'];
$countries = "ES-US";
$category = "Comedy"; ?>


<div id="viewsdropdown">

<p>
View videos with
  <form name="views" method="POST" action="random.php">
        <select name='views' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
             <option selected value='0'>0</option>
             <option  value='50'>50</option>
             <option  value='100'>100</option>
             <option  value='500'>500</option>
             <option  value='5000'>5,000</option>
             <option  value='35000'>35,000</option>
             <option  value='75000'>75,000</option>
             <option  value='125000'>125,000</option>
             <option  value='150000'>150,000</option>
             <option  value='250000'>250,000</option>
             <option  value='500000'>500,000</option>
             <option  value='1000000'>1,000,000</option>
             <option  value='3000000'>3,000,000</option>
             <option  value='5000000'>5,000,000</option>
             <option  value='10000000'>10,000,000</option>
             <option  value='15000000'>15,000,000</option>
             <option  value='20000000'>20,000,000</option>
    </select>
        </form>
  <p>views or more
  </p>

</div>

<div id="videocenter">
  <?php


$url = "http://flyhour.tv/bots/api/index.php?type=2&countries=".$countries."&category=".$category."&views=".$views;



$file = $url;



echo $file

?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

edited code:

```
<body>
<?php 
$views = (int) $_POST['views'];
$countries = "ES-US";
$category = "Comedy"; ?>
<div id="viewsdropdown">

<p>
View videos with
  <form name="views" method="POST" action="random.php">
        <select name='views' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
            <? $views_options = array (50, 100, 500, 5000, 35000, 75000, 125000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 1000000, 3000000, 5000000, 10000000, 15000000, 20000000);

foreach($views_options as $number_of_views) {
    echo '<option value="' . $number_of_views . '"' . ($_POST['views']==35000 ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . number_format($number_of_views) . '</option>';
}?>
    </select>
        </form>
  <p>views or more
  </p>

</div>

<div id="videocenter">
  <?php


$url = "http://flyhour.tv/bots/api/index.php?type=2&countries=".$countries."&category=".$category."&views=".$views;



$file = $url;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each "option" line, add the following PHP script:

```
<option  value='35000'<?= $_POST['views']==35000 ? ' selected="selected" : '' ?>>35,000</option>
```

Even better, you can change the entire block to something like this:

```
$views_options = array (50, 100, 500, 5000, 35000, 75000, 125000);

foreach($views_options as $number_of_views) {
    echo '<option value="' . $number_of_views . '"' . ($_POST['views']==35000 ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . number_format($number_of_views) . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Yup - I'd definitely go down the loop route; saved me the effort of tweaking my answer as well ;)

Comment: it seems we are on the right track but when i click on a number it gives me another number than the one clicked when the page rereshes.(you can see that on the test site right now). That is the issue when i leave 0 out of the array. when i add 0 to the array whichever number i select it always returns 0.

ps. the server error was on your first suggestion

Comment: If there was a server error on the first suggestion it probably fell over on the use of PHP shorthand tags `<?=` can simply be replaced with `<?php echo ` if that's the case.

Comment: You are hard-coding the 35000 value. Try this:
echo '<option value="' . $number_of_views . '"' . ($_POST['views']==$number_of_views ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . number_format($number_of_views) . '</option>';

Comment: WOW, great, i cant thank you enough, you helped me so much and in no time at all. I really appreciate it.

Comment: ps. i changed post to get to avoid browser popup regarding form resubmission - seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Since you're POSTing the form the value for views should always exists in the $_POST (or, as you're using it $_REQUEST) superglobal...

So what you'll need is something like:

```
<?php
$views = (int) $_REQUEST['views'];
$countries = "ES-US";
$category = "Comedy"; 
?>

<div id="viewsdropdown">

<p>
View videos with
  <form name="views" method="POST" action="random.php">
        <select name='views' onChange='document.views.submit()'>
             <option value='0'<?php echo !$iViews ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>0</option>
             <option value='50'<?php echo $iViews > 49 && $iViews < 100 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>50</option>
             <option value='100'<?php echo $iViews > 99 && $iViews < 500 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>100</option>
             <option value='500'<?php echo $iViews > 499 && $iViews < 5000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>500</option>
             <option value='5000'<?php echo $iViews > 4999 && $iViews < 35000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>5,000</option>
             <option value='35000'<?php echo $iViews > 34999 && $iViews < 75000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>35,000</option>
             <option value='75000'<?php echo $iViews > 74999 && $iViews < 125000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>75,000</option>
             <option value='125000'<?php echo $iViews > 124999 && $iViews < 150000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>125,000</option>
             <option value='150000'<?php echo $iViews > 149999 && $iViews < 250000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>150,000</option>
             <option value='250000'<?php echo $iViews > 249999 && $iViews < 500000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>250,000</option>
             <option value='500000'<?php echo $iViews > 499999 && $iViews < 1000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>500,000</option>
             <option value='1000000'<?php echo $iViews > 999999 && $iViews < 3000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>1,000,000</option>
             <option value='3000000'<?php echo $iViews > 2999999 && $iViews < 5000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>3,000,000</option>
             <option value='5000000'<?php echo $iViews > 4999999 && $iViews < 10000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>5,000,000</option>
             <option value='10000000'<?php echo $iViews > 9999999 && $iViews < 15000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>10,000,000</option>
             <option value='15000000'<?php echo $iViews > 14999999 && $iViews < 20000000 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>15,000,000</option>
             <option value='20000000'<?php echo $iViews > 19999999 ? " selected=\"selected\"" : ""; ?>>20,000,000</option>
    </select>
</form>

// ... and so on ...
```

Comment: Yeah, we posted within a couple of seconds of each other ... since Ayman's answer was tidier, I upvoted his answer ;)